# How to open database relationship diagram (schema) in Visual Studio through database connection?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013

I've got database connection available in the Server Explorer menu in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. There is a list of tables, but I can't find way to show database schema.

Is it possible to show schema in VS2013 and if yes, how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built in Server Explorer menu, I would download the Microsoft SQL Management Studio for free. It will allow you to view, edit and manage the schema no problem as well as letting you graph everything into diagrams for a better visual picture of entire databases.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016